# Call JSON inside AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to call a json data inside my AJAX success. I'm still new on manipulating json and AJAX. Can somebody help me on how to access my json data which is from another URL? And I want to compare the `id` to the JSON data. Here's my code so far:

```
function getCard(id){

        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              data: "id=" + id,
              success: function(data){

                        #call JSON data here from another URL
                        # Is it possible to call another AJAX here?

                       }
         });
    }
```

Comment: why dont you try it?

Comment: I would use a callback function to keep everything clean.

Comment: It is possible. Try nesting another `$.ajax` call.

Comment: where is your url? and your json would be the argument passed on the success function which in this case is `data` if you server side logic is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            method: "post",
            data: "id=" + id,
            success:function(data) {
                // success goes here
                  $.ajax({
                       url: "url",
                       async:false,
                       method: "post",
                      data: "id=" + id,
                           success:function(json) {
                                   JSON.parse(json);

                                  // compare data and json here
                          },
                         error: function(){
                        // error code goes here
                       }
                }); 
            },
            error: function(){
                // error code goes here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

yes Zuma you can call another Ajax inside Success function of Ajax call. Below is the example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url1,
        data: data1,
        success: function(data){                
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: url2,
                data: data2,
                success: function(data){

            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

function getCard(id){

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "Get",
          url: "发送请求的地址",
          data: "id=" + id,
          success: function(data){

                    #call JSON data here from another URL
                    # if success,you can call another AJAX.
                    # Is it possible to call another AJAX here?
                    # yes!

                   }
     });
}
```